# make links active in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, hyperlink

I have this list of links in Laravel 5.3

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     <li class="list-group-item text-right"><a href="{{url('/product/'.$category->id)}}">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

How can I make the current link active

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Request` if the current one matches when you are printing the `li` and then include the class `active`.

This will add `active` class when the URI is `/product/1`.

`{{ Request::is('/product/1') ? 'active' : null }}`

In your code:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     <li class="list-group-item text-right {{ Request::is('/product/'.$category->id) ? 'active' : null }}"><a href="{{url('/product/'.$category->id)}}">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @user5565240 Did you inspect the element and see the class `active` is not added?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     <li class="list-group-item text-right"><a href="{{url('/product/'.$category->id)}}" class="{{ Request::is('/product/'.$category->id) ? 'active' : null }}">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

That is what you need class should be applied to link not li

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any good  simple solution how to do that. But I came up with my solution. You can use it in Laravel 5.6 and it work very well.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

<li class="list-group-item @if(Request::fullUrl() === route('category.index', strtolower($category->name))) active @endif">
<a href="{{ route('category.index', strtolower($category->name))}}">{{$category->name}}</a></li>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally used this one.

```
class="{{ request()->routeIs('user.dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}"
```

And to make active on multiple routes.

```
class="{{ request()
    ->routeIs('user.dashboard', 'user.channels') ? 'active' : '' }}"
```